# Silverlight 5 White Screen XP and IE8 only

Tags: silverlight, internet-explorer-8, windows-xp

We are running into an issue with our users and are out of ideas on what the issue is hoping someone might have run into something similar.

It only occurs on Windows XP IE8 machines, we know this because users that were regularly seeing the issue on XP IE8, after being upgraded to Windows 7 IE8 and they have not seen the issue again.

Any assistance in capturing more detail would be greatly appreciated as well.

When users load the url to the silverlight application the following error occurs. If they refresh (F5) the page 3-4 times or so eventually the page loads successfully.

Here are the details of the error we see: 
Webpage error details

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; GTB7.4;     .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; MS-RTC LM 8; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Tue, 29 Jan 2013 17:50:13 UTC

Message: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application 
Code: 2103    
Category: InitializeError       
Message: 2103 An error has occurred.     
Line: 58
Char: 13
Code: 0
URI:
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't tell us much. Do you know what the users were doing at the time?

Comment: They were loading the silverlight application.

Comment: It's probably a caching issue. Does the problem occur just after you upload a new version of the app?

Comment: It occurs every time the user opens the application until they refresh enough to get it to load. So for instance they open it up this morning press F5 3-4 times to get it to load work all day close at the end of the day. Tomorrow morning they open it back up they will have to F5 again to get it to load up again.

Answer (score 0):

Add a stamp to the page URL which host your SL app,
and change it when the user refreshes. I.e:

```
www.blahblah.com/silverlightTestPage.aspx?stamp={random string}
```

This suboptimal browser thought it didn't not need to reload the page and SL app if the URL didn't change.